# Integrated shielding for a space ship

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction, spaceships, energy

I came up with a concept for a shielding system for space vessels. The outer hull plating is made up of a special material, like modified steel perhaps. Energy from the ship's main power source is used to strengthen the atomic bonds in the material, making it extremely hard. My hope is that this could be used to defend against a variety of things, such as explosives, energy weapons, radiation, physical impacts, etc. Would a system like this be possible?

Comment: Research explosive plating for tanks. Yes, that is a thing.

Comment: As it stands this is fairly opinion-based - questions like these deep into the fantastic really need a lot of setting details to work, since we can't reference the real world to fill in the gaps and there's a lot of places where we have to fill in 'I guess? We have no idea how to do that, or even where to begin trying to do that.'

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Check out the [tour] and [help] to get an idea of how the site functions.  Good luck with your world building.

Comment: I think a question that asked how the application of power could improve the strength of ship based armor could be useful.  As it stands there are too many questions here and not enough detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a structural integrity field to me. Perhaps an alloy which conducts your energy source and causes it to strengthen the alloys atomic bonds. Depending on the surface area of your ships hull and how much power your power source can generate, you could make the hull harder than diamond. Modern munitions (bullets and shells) would be made obsolete.
You could even use the energy from the impact to strengthen the material AT the impact area.

Answer (score 1):

### Interesting...

I think Larry Niven has designed something similar with his GP hulls.

See: http://larryniven.wikia.com/wiki/GP_Hull

The variant you have thought up simply uses X amount of energy to accomplish it. However, without knowing specifics, I don't believe we can answer how much power would be consumed. I'm wondering if this question might be better placed in a physics discussion exchange.

### EDIT :

Rephrase the question to ask specifically how a certain substance (take carbon steel) might be strengthened (or not) with the addition of powering its molecular structure. I don't know, but I'm guessing no.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Meta-materials, While these wont cover all types of radiation, In theory you could design one that would effectively cloak an object from some parts of the electromagnetic spectrum, such as x-rays, and gamma-rays.

While the practical limits of this probably will prevent gamma rays, most penetrating radiation is electromagnetic.  For example alpha radiation can be stopped by a few sheets of paper.

Basically you could bend gamma rays around the spacecraft so it doesn't go through it.

The same effect would work on lasers, however in the real world there is still some heat exchanged.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial_cloaking